# permission to open pdf file in 3rd party app

Tags: android, android-intent, permissions

I'm trying to open a pdf file from my app , on my device currently installed 3 3rd party apps to open pdf file. when the system asks me on witch of them to open the pdf, how can i know if the user selects one and presses "ok" or "decline"? my actions defined by if he accepts or declines

This is in my class :

```
String path="...../file.pdf";
Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(path)), "application/pdf");
startActivityForResult(intent, 225);
```

And then in the activity :

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { 
    // Check which request we're responding to 
    if (requestCode == 225) { 
            // Make sure the request was successful if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) 
    } else {
        
    } 
}
```

**screen shot for example**
[image]

Comment: please post some codes

Comment: this is im my class : String path="...../file.pdf";
Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(path)), "application/pdf");
startActivityForResult(intent, 225);

Comment: and then in the activity :  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // Check which request we're responding to
    if (requestCode == 225) {
        // Make sure the request was successful
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
           
        }else{
    }

Comment: Edit your question and include this code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how can i know if the user selects one and presses "ok" or "decline"?

You can't. `ACTION_VIEW` that is used to open a pdf in an external app does not give back any information. You can use `startActivityForResult()` but it will not have any effect because a result will not be set. Also see [ACTION_VIEW](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_VIEW) documentation.

You should redesign your concept/logic so that it does not depend on this information.

Answer (score 1):

You can find all of the apps on the device that can service your Intent using the following code:

```
List<ResolveInfo> pkgAppsList = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities( mainIntent, 0);
```

You can use the information from this to query the packages and learn their display name and icons (SO has plenty of answers how to do that).

You can create your own Dialog from within your app that looks identical to the system dialog. In this way you'll be able to track hits and pass the intent to the selected package directly.

Good luck!